# Wordpress woo commerce products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Does anybody know how in wordpress theme make something like on the screen shot? As you can see, there is cat food, and depending upon the weight there is different prices. Link to the screen shot webpage (http://zveruga.net/tovary-dlya-koshek/sukhie_korma/)

Thank you in advance !

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you please rephrase and/or add more detail? Could you explain the difference between the screenshot on the left versus the one of the right?

Comment: What you're after are Woocommerce "product variations", and while setting up your store this way is beyond the scope of help here, see [this document](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/) on their site.

Comment: @helgatheviking Ok, I have the Wordpress woocommerce theme. I want to make a store to sell the food for pets. I had loaded all my products variations, description and images. What I want to do now, is like on the screen shot (screen shot is not from my web site). There is no difference between left and right, it just 2 different products. But here you can see that this cat food in different variations, and you can see that for 300 gram it cost 241p for 1.4 kg the price is 880p and so on

Comment: So you want the product archive loop to list the available variations for each product?

Comment: @ helgatheviking yes )